# The bottom of my cup is transparent with black speck

Tags: cycles-render-engine

[image]

I am following Blender Guru tutorial on the coffee cup. Everything seems to flow smoothly until I finished and realised that coffee does not meet the bottom of the cup. When I check the liquid (coffee) and the cup individually, it seems normal. Only when I added the liquid to the cup that the black speck and gap appear

Comment: That's probably the refraction in the glass